# How to pass output.path parm to webpack during build?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, package.json

Hi I am looking for instructions on how to pass a specific output.path value to webpack during the react build.  How would I modify my build command below to pass a specific output path to webpack?

```
"scripts": {
    "copy:html": "yarn cpy body.html env.js \"./dist\"",
    "build": "yarn clean && yarn copy:html && npx webpack --env.mode production",
```

how to pass template path?

HtmlWebPackPlugin({
template:

Comment: You can pass it via environment variables. Does https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/#env not work?